# gitlab issue types and how to create new ones

Tags: gitlab, customization, issue-tracking

Ok, i'm using Giltab  and noticed this

[image]

then found and read this [docs about issue types](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/issue_types.html).

What it looks like is that i can use real issue types instead labels to identify an issue as a (e.g.) bug, a proposal, a enhancement, a new feature request, etc, but i connot understand if i can create new issue types.

Is there anyone who managed to used this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question, I too was interested in taking this approach.

From doing some digging, it appears that the Type was just introduced so that Incidents can also be tracked alongside Issues. So it is not currently possible to create a Type such as "Bug", "Feature", etc like you might do in other tools like Jira. You still need to use labels for categorizing your issues.

Comment: A workaround might be to use Labels.

Answer (score 8):

Gitlab is tracking an issue for creating custom issues types. Current proposal  and status can be tracked here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/118666